# why do my breaker go off when using my new kettle?

Tags: short-circuit

Ok...this isnt a hi end electronics question but help me out please. I bought his teamaker with the following details:

220-2240v 50hz , 1500-2000w

My extension cord, Emkay ek-03 is:

230v, 13a max, 50-60hz

The breaker goes off after a minute of operation. I am in a shared apartment and i know the landlord have a fridge. It appears i should be able to boil onelitre of water sucessfully at least at midnight when everyone is asleep.

The breaker is accessible to me but i was able to read nothing from its cover as it is all white.

Is it my extension cords fuse or the breaker? Can breakers be programmed to block heaters or something (dont laugh). I find it hard to believe onlyme wants to make tea (except the landlord).

I wanna plug it directly to socket but am afraid of electrical fire or losing its warranty.

Comment: How long is your extension cord?  Any idea of it's size?

Comment: Please do a basic google search on your extension cord. It is an unsafe product and has been recalled. Destroy it.

Comment: To save you a search: http://unsafeproducts.eu/recall/022705-three-sockets-extension-cord-emkay ("Risk of electric shock. Presence of earth contact but missing internal earth wire.")

Answer (score 1):

A good time to read the data, which came with your kettle.  Toasters/Kettles are meant to plug directly into the wall.

[Risk of Electric Shock](https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=main.weeklyOverview&web_report_id=114&Year=2005&Category=Electrical%20appliances%20and%20equipment)  It's a bit old (2005 warning), but maybe you should get a new extension cord.  Something with a bigger wire size.

[image: EMKAY EK-03]

Every time you trip the breaker, you are putting stress on the wiring and the circuit breaker.  I'd plug it directly into the wall and see if it works.      The worst that can happen is the breaker will trip again.

At 230V, a 2000W kettle would draw 8.7A.  Standard British outlet is rated at 13A.  So it should work.

But you have no idea what else is plugged in to the outlet.  Try another outlet (as in visit a friend for tea and bring the kettle to test).  If it works, it is not the kettle.

You have 3 outlets on your extension cord.  Plug a lamp into an outlet.  Turn it on.  Turn on your kettle.  If the light dims as kettle starts to work, your circuit is too long and something else is on the circuit.  If it does not dim, then you should not have any problems.

Either way, the first step is to plug your kettle directly into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

At first you dont need worry to much about direct plugging.
If the Installation is halfway decent, the breaker in the
fuse box is to avoid exactly fire or malefunction. You can
calmly try your kettle without an extension cord.

With an output of max 2000W at 230V the current will be
2000W/230V=8,7A (Ampere).
At 110V: 2000W/110V=18,2A

Maybe you can try your kettle by a friend or another
electrical device(s in addition to reach 2000W) with similar
power output with
or without your extension cord to work out the problem.

If the breaker disrupt without the extension cord
maybe its strained with other devices or a fault in the installation.

Or just the breakers value is to low for an output like
your kettle (You wrote this is not to read, isnt it?).
Maybe the seller should be capable to test your kettle and your
cord properly.

Have luck!

Hoiberl